# Propagation of Absolute Error in Weighted Linear Regression

Tags: weighted-regression, error-propagation

This is probably relatively trivial, but I am having a difficult time searching for what I want.

I have a set of measurements with a well-defined variance, and I'm performing a weighted least squares calculation to get a line of best fit. The slope of this line is an experimental observable, so getting a well-defined variance for this line is important for our further data analysis.

However, WLS only considers the relative weights of the data points in determining its variance. For example, if I take a dataset and double the variance for each point, the calculated variance on the slope is unchanged. What is the best way to propagate higher uncertainty in the individual points to a higher uncertainty in the calculated slope?

Comment: You could use Bayesian methods where you have a prior, or you could use regularization (penalized estimation) towards some "natural" value for the slope. Maybe these keywords could help you move forward.